# Convert id HEX <> BIN in Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, uuid

Is there a way to use UUID primary key with Eloquent ORM? UUID is stored in MySQL as BINARY(16). Since it's neither human readable nor HTTP safe, it would be great if there's a way to have id in HEX format in ORM objects, to read and use in *::find()* or *::where()* methods.

I already have set new key generation with help of this article: http://garrettstjohn.com/article/using-uuids-laravel-eloquent-orm/

Comment: Question ended with migration to PostgreSQL, which has native uuid type support.